# Limiting maximum records per key in MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

I've a table for storing products as per the following structure...

id      shop_id        product_id        product_title

Every shop selects a plan, and accordingly it can stored N products in this tables. N is different for every shop.

**Problem Statement**: While doing insert operation in the table, total number of entries per shop_id can't be more than N.

I can count the #products before every insert operation, and then decide whether new entry should go in the table or be ignored. The operations are triggered by events received, and it may be in millions. So it doesn't seem to efficient. Performance is the key.

Is there a better way?

Comment: that's the ONLY way to do it. either via a `constraint` (which mysql doesn't support), or an on-insert trigger - but regardless of HOW you do it, you'd have to count existing records to see if the limit is being approached/exceeded. whether it's a "live" count, or checking a "total records" field elsewhere, you're still going to have to do or maintain a record inventory.

Comment: Just insert, when you pull data out limit it by that number N, don't limit anything at insert stage. That way you didn't misuse anything. You can use event scheduler to "clean" any products that are extra (count goes over N assigned to a shop), and have it run daily.

Comment: If you don't want to count on each inset operation, you can save that count value somewhere (table, for example) and update after a successfull insert/remove; this way, before an insert, you can check that number without doing any query.

Comment: If there's no way to avoid counting before every stage, idea by @N.B. seems to be the best way forward.

Answer (score 1):

I Think you should use a stored procedure so you can delegate the validations to MySql and not to PHP, here is an example of what you might need, just be sure to replace the table names and columns names properly.

If you are worried about the performance you should check the indexes of the tables for better performance.

Procedure

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS storeProduct//
CREATE PROCEDURE storeProduct(IN shopId INT, IN productId INT, IN productTitle VARCHAR(255))
LANGUAGE SQL MODIFIES SQL DATA SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN
    /*Here we get the plan for the shop*/
    SET @N = (SELECT plan FROM planTable WHERE shop_id = shopId);

    /*NOW WE COUNT THE PRODUCTS THAT ARE STORED WITH THE shop_id*/
    SET @COUNT = (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM storing_products WHERE shop_id = shopId);

    /*NOW WE CHECK IF WE CAN STORE THE PRODUCTS OR NOT*/
    IF @COUNT < @N THEN
        /*YES WE CAN INSERT*/
        INSERT INTO storing_products(shop_id, product_id, product_title)
        VALUES (shopId, productId, productTitle);
        /*1 means that the insert acording to the plan is ok*/
        SELECT 1 AS 'RESULT';
    ELSE
        /*NO WE CAN NOT INSERT*/
        /*0 means that the insert acording to the plan is not ok*/
        SELECT 0 AS 'RESULT';
    END IF;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Now you can call it from PHP just like

```
<?php
    //....
    $result = $link->query("CALL storeProduct($shop_id, $product_id, $product_title);");
    //....
?>
```

or whatever you do

the answer is like

```
+--------+
| RESULT |
+--------+
|      1 |
+--------+
```

if its ok or

```
+--------+
| RESULT |
+--------+
|      0 |
+--------+
```

if not

I hope it will help

Greetings

Comment: Thanks @Jhonny for sharing the clean code. However, overall the problem remains same. I've to count before every insert, and as there're many different shops enrolled and we will keep on receiving the events, I believe this may not be the very efficient way.

Comment: Mm, too bad, but you have always to make the count!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to count at insertion time, you can maintain count in another table than can be referred while insertion

```
shop_id     max_product    product_count   insertion_allowed
------------------------------------------------------------
1           1000           50              1
2           2000           101             1
3           100            100             0
```

Two approaches:

1. compare product_count and max_product and insert when product_count is smaller than max_product. After successful insertion increment product_count of corresponding shop_id.
2. Alternatively, you may use insertion_allowed flag to check condition and after each successful insertion increment the product_count by 1 of corresponding shop_id.

Hope this will help you.
Please share performance improvement statistics of the approach(if you can). It may help others in choosing better approach.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach without store procedure.

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `prod_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=19 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

You can do an insert with select. It's a little bit more efficient of two separate queries. The trick is if the select returns empty rows, then no insert happens:

```
$prod_id = 12;
$N = 3;

$qry = "insert into test (prod_id)
(select $prod_id FROM test WHERE prod_id=$prod_id HAVING count(id) <= $N )";
```