# Is it possible to limit the number of rows per partition key and clustering column

Tags: cassandra

Is is possible to limit the no. of rows per partition/clustering column. Eg, say for an article, I want to limit the no. of comments per article to say 20. I also want that if 21st article is added then the oldest one is deleted and the new one is inserted. I can think of how this could be controlled at application level but could it be controlled at the database level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cassandra does not support any out-of-box functionality which can limit the number of partition by rows. In your application, you will have to constantly delete a lot of data from Cassandra, which will create tombstones and is not the recommended way to use Cassandra.

In a database like MySQL, you can achieve the same by using stored procedures. A similar approach is covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31970713/3921053).